# Java Sockets: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?)

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have a big problem. I have developped a client-server application. A client thread sends a serialized object to the server and the server sends back a serialized object. Currently I'm using one server and 10 client threads and after about 30 seconds I get the error message from each client thread (IOException):

> No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect

If I'm looking in netstat then I see that there are a lot of connections created and it is growing and growing and all connections are in `TIME_WAIT` state.

I don't know why. I close the sockets in the server and in the clients everytime in a finally block. Here is some code:

In the server I have in socketHandlerThread:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
serverSocket.setSoTimeout(5000);
while(true) {
       Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
}
```

The new socket is then put on a LinkedBlockingQueue and a worker thread takes the socket and makes the following:

```
try {
      outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
      outputStream.flush();
      inStream = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
      ClientRequest clientRequest = (ClientRequest) inStream.readObject();
...
      outputStream.writeObject(serverResponse);
      outputStream.flush();
} catch....
} finally {
                if (inStream != null) {
                    inStream.close();
                }
                if (outputStream != null) {
                    outputStream.close();
                }
                if (socket != null) {
                    socket.close();
                }
}
```

On the client side I have the following code:

```
    try {
        socket = new Socket(host, port);
        outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
        outputStream.flush();
        inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
        outputStream.writeObject(request);
        outputStream.flush();
        Object serverResponse = inputStream.readObject();
   } catch....
   } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.close();
            }
            if (socket != null) {
                socket.close();
            }
   }
```

Can somebody help? I really don't know what mistake I made. I seems that the sockets get no closed but I don't know why.

Could it be the problem that I put the sockets on a queue on the server side so that the socket is somehow copied?

Edit: If I put the client and the server each on a different Amazon EC2 classic instance running Linux AMI then it works. Could it be a problem with Windows or is the problem simply that I was running the Clients and servers on the same machine (my local pc)?

Does somebody see a bug in my code?

Edit2: As said above on EC2 instances it works but if I use netstat it shows still a lot of lines saying `TIME_WAIT`.

Here are screenshots:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzERdJrwWrNCWjhReGhpR2FBMUU/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzERdJrwWrNCOG1TWGo5YmxlaTg/view?usp=sharing

First screenshot is from windows. "WARTEND" means "WAITING" (it is german).

The second screenshot is from Amazon EC2 (to the left the client machine, to the right the server machine).

Comment: Just a thought -- why not use RMI? RMI handles the socket thread issue.

Comment: I have to use this style unfortunately.

Comment: What does netstat really say? 'Waiting' is not a port state.

Comment: But you haven't answered mine. *netstat* can print a dozen or so states, but 'Waiting' isn't one of them. There are several with `_WAIT` in the name. Which is it?

Comment: What command do I have to put? Just writing netstat in the command console? Or with some arguments?

Comment: I am asking you what it *already* printed. If you don't know how to run it I don't see how you can possibly assert that it printed anything at all. You could try `netstat -anp tcp` to get output just for TCP, but please report it accurately. Paste a line or two of its output into the question.

Comment: You are trying to make too many connections too quickly and are running out of local ports. If that's due to a bug, fix the bug. (Why don't you reuse connections?!) If you really are trying to make so many connections, you'll need to catch this case, wait a bit, and try again.

Comment: Can you try what happens if on the server side you put in a `Thread.sleep(3000);` before you start closing the socket?

Comment: I've added some screenshots

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TIME-WAIT is entered *after* the connection is closed at both ends. It lasts for a couple of minutes, for data integrity reasons.

If the buffer problem is due to TIME-WAIT states at the server, the solution is to make the server be the peer that first receives the close. That will shift the TIME-WAIT state to the client, where it is benign.

You can do that by putting your server-side request handling into a loop, so that it can handle multiple requests per connection, and so that the server only closes the socket when it reaches end of stream on it.

```
for (;;)
{
    try
    {
        ClientRequest clientRequest = (ClientRequest) inStream.readObject();
        ...
        outputStream.writeObject(serverResponse);
        outputStream.flush();
    }
    catch (EOFException exc)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

If you then implement connection-pooling at the client, you will massively reduce the number of connections, which will further reduce the incidence of the buffer problem.

Comment: And your problem on the German Windows machine is that you're running the server and the client on the same host, and creating zillions of connections, which isn't a realistic test anyway.

Comment: A client makes a connection to the server and after he got the response, he closes the connection. Then a new connection is established and so on.... Thus, I have a lot of connections. Your solution is good but I'm not allowed to change this (no connection pooling). Anyway, should the server still wait for a end of stream and then closing? He receives only one object. And can the time-way not be reduced to 1 second or less? Why is the time-wait state benign at the client? If I have too much time waits at the client, the client cannot create new connections.

Comment: You should still implement the loop at the server, for the reason I mentioned. `TIME_WAIT` is benign at the client because it isn't multiplied by the number of clients as it is at the server: it only applies to the client's own connections. You should certainly implement connection-pooling as well if you really want to solve this problem, and you should so advise anyone who thinks they should stop you.

Comment: Thanks but I don't know exactly what you mean with the loop at the server. Could you give some small example code? The clients send only one object, the server sends a answer but and closes the connection. So I don't have several requests per connection.

Comment: But you should code your server as though you do, that's the point. Just a loop around the request/response handler, that terminates when `EOFException` is caught.

Comment: Ok, I saw your code example. Thank you very much. But... in the first iteration there is an object to read and one to write, so everything ok. But in the second iteration it will block at the instream.readObject.

Comment: No. As I already said, it terminates when `EOFException` is caught. That happens when the client closes the connection. Or, when and if you introduce connection pooling, it will process more requests. You could always try it, instead of just guessing.

Comment: I will go with your solution of a connection pool. ;) I will open a follow up thread on stackoverflow for this problem.

Comment: Just a short last question. Is the order of closing the inputStream, outputStream and socket in the client and server in my above code ok?

Comment: Is it possible to reduce the time-wait on Linux, say to 1second? Or can I use SO_REUSEADDR?

Comment: Looping at the server is essential. Connection pooling is desirable. They aren't the same thing. You should close the output stream first, then the socket I n a finally block for that close. It isn't necessary to close the input stream as well, and it is only necessary to close the socket if closing the output stream failed. It is neither possible nor desirable to reduce `TIME-WAIT` to one second. It's an important part of TCP data integrity. `SO_REUSEADDR` won't solve a buffer exhaustion problem.

Comment: In my code, as you can see above, I closed in the finally block the inputStream, the outputStream and the socket in squence. Is this the cause of my problems or should this still work?

Comment: It is not the cause of this problem. It's only the right way to do it.