# Java: establishing socket connection pool

Tags: java, sockets, queue, connection-pooling

I have a client-server application using Java sockets. Until now it works in the following way:

The client opens a socket connection to the server. The socketHandler thread of the server puts the new socket onto a LinkedBlockingQueue. A Worker thread takes a socket from the queue and gets and reads an object from the stream (the clients send object to the server) and writes an answer back to the client and closes the socket.

But now I want to create a connection pool so that the connections can be kept open but I still want the LinkedBlockingQueud.

My idea is that each new connection is put on a queue, lets call it openSocketQueue, and then the socketHandler thread (or some other thread) iterates over the openSocketQueue and checks if there is new data available (without reading the data). If the data is available, it removes the socket from the queue and puts it on the LinkedBlockingQueue. After the worker has finished the socket is not closed but put back onto the openSocketQueue.

Is this reasonable? How an I iterate over sockets checking if there is new data avialble in an efficient way?

By the way, I cannot change to NIO because I don't have time for this.

Comment: Since you want to avoid using the asynchronous benefits of NIO this is the only option left.So you only want to use sockets. Other packages like netty , mina can also help. If you want to use the "Reactor design pattern" then the above packages will help. Else you would need to resort to looping.

Comment: What about using SO_REUSEADDR with sockets?

Comment: `SO_REUSEADDR` doesn't have anything to do with this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are totally confused.

Connection pooling is implemented *at the client:* instead of calling `new Socket()` you look in a collection keyed by the target IP:port; instead of closing you return the connection to the pool; and you add a thread that closes sockets in the pool that have been there for too long, e.g. 15 seconds.

All you need at the server is a thread per connection that loops reading requests until EOS, as we discussed in your [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26409766/207421). None of this `available()/LinkedBlockingQueue` stuff.